# Anonymous authentication - 401.2 error (IIS7.5)

Tags: permissions, authentication, iis

I am trying to set up Anonymous Authentication for an IIS web site.

I checked Anonymous Authentication is enabled and all other methods are disabled.

I need to use a specific user for Anonymous user identity (IIS_MY_USER), I've entered the user in Edit Anonymous Authentication Credentials settings.

I am getting error 401.2 when opening the website on the server (localhost) with error message 
HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized 
You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers

The website directory is accessible to the user (it is actually accessible to Everyone). 
When I add IIS_MY_USER to Administrators group, it works.

What may be causing this problem?

The server is IIS 7.5 on W2008 R2

Comment: Does IIS_MY_USER have permission to the actual folders on the server?

Comment: Not explicitly, but "Everyone" has "Full Control" permission for the web app folder and subfolders/files. Are there some other folders for which permissions are required too?